# How to limit users writing post to every 15 minutes in firebase real-time database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using firebase real-time database.

I'm trying to limit users to allow them post only after minimum of 15 minutes from their latest post (this is to prevent posts looking like chat).

How would I achieve this?

What I've tried is, including timestamp for every post and calculate the time difference from the current time if user tries to post a new one. This would work, but if the user deletes the previous post, then the user would be able to post again right away. So I need a different approach.

What algorithm could I implement?

Thank you Merry Christmas!

Comment: One possible solution is to store the last post time on the user, instead of the individual post?

Comment: @grooveplex so I do I make an update to the user's property at every posts they make?

Comment: That would work, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I would do it is like this.  Require the client app to make a multi-location update, writing both the post and the timestamp.  The timestamp would be stored per-user, as well as in the post.  You could write a security rule on the node containing the posts that checks all of the the following must be true in order for the write to succeed:

1. The per-user timestamp was only specified with ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
2. The per-user timestamp is at least 15 minutes later than the existing value (or, if not existing, skip this check)
3. The post's own timestamp was also specified to have the same value

Comment: Thank you for the answer! extra step but advanced security check i'll try implement and see how it goes!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new field to store the post from user

```
 User {
   . . . , 
  PostHistory{
 Post1: [timestamp],
 Post2: [timestamp]
 . . . 
 },
 }
```

And then every time user create a new post you can check with the postHistory.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Though should I post timestamp for every post they make? or just one and update that one only?

Comment: I think you should keep every post because for later you can use this data